Set aspect ratio of plot to square with geographic map
I am trying to make a scatterplot on top of a world map, and I want to make the plot a 6" by 6" square. This would involve stretching the aspect ratio of the map, and also the difference between xmax-xmin and ymax-ymin aren't equal which complicates things. Here's my code so far and here's the figure it produces.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
#====================================================================
y_pred = np.random.random((389, 28, 14))
world = gpd.read_file("ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp")

min_lat = 19.25
max_lat = -5.75
min_lon = 18.5
max_lon = 31.5

lat = np.tile(np.arange(max_lat, min_lat-0.5, -0.5).reshape(-1, 1), (1, int(max_lon - min_lon+1)))
lon = np.tile(np.arange(min_lon, max_lon+1, 1).reshape(1, -1), (int((max_lat - min_lat)*2)+1, 1))

#====================================================================
''' Plot map '''
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=max(y_pred.ravel()))

fig_map, ax_map = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,6), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
fig_map.set_size_inches(6, 6)

map = ax_map.scatter(x=lon, y=lat, c=y_pred[date_idx], s=4, cmap='bwr', norm=norm)

world.plot(ax=ax_map, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', linewidth=.5, alpha=1)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax_map)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(map, cax=cax)

ax_map.set_xlim(-20, 60)
ax_map.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax_map.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
fig_map.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)


Can you describe your problem further? What's the main problem you're facing? Also, if there are any traceback, please provide it (in text and
preferably formatted as code).

This question is similar to: When using matplotlib, how do I set the on-screen lengths of the x and y axes to be equal without changing the limits of either axis?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have three incompatible constraints: equal aspect ratio, unequal axes limits, and wanting a square plot.  Mathematically you are going to have to give up one of the three constraints
